# numpy: check safe convertibility of array-like objects, includings nested lists

Tags: numpy, casting

I have a function which accepts array-like objects (i.e. np.ndarray or possibly nested lists/tuples). I need to check whether a given object can be safely coerced to a given target dtype (e.g. `float`).

The function `np.can_cast(...)` with the default `casting='safe'` is somewhat handy, but

- only acceps np.ndarray (or scalars), not for lists/tuples;
- does not consider the actual data range, only source dtype (e.g. `np.can_cast(np.ndarray([1],dtype='int64'),'int32')` is `False` even though `1` is perfectly representable in int32.

So two separate questions:

- How can I check that array-like sequence is safely convertible to a dtype? (`np.array([1.1,2.2,3.3],dtype='i')` will happily truncate the floats)
- How can I check that a np.ndarray is safely convertible to a target dtype based on actual values in the array?

Comment: How does your function handle the list input?  With a `np.array` wrapper?  I doubt if you can avoid that when checking - un

Comment: The `np.array` wrapper does possibly unsafe conversions. So I currently traverse flattened sequence and call `np.can_convert` for each scalar item, like: `if isinstance(value,(list,tuple)): for item in flatten(value): if not np.can_convert(item[i],target_dtype): raise TypeError(...)`